# Variables of Spock test are not accessible in Evaluate Expression dialog while debugging in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, spock

In the following Spock test:

```
def 'simple assertion'() {
    expect:
    Math.max(a, b) == max

    where:
    a | b | max
    3 | 5 | 5
    4 | 9 | 9
    }
```

When setting a breakpoint in the code line at the expect block, it is not possible to access the value of the variables `(a, b)` from the Evaluate Expression... dialog while debugging. The returned exception is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: a, b for class: DUMMY
```

The only way around it is by manually copying the data from the `where` part into the evaluate expression dialog.

How can I use **evaluate expression** WITHOUT having to manually copy the values from the `where` part of the test?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2022.1 running on macOS 12 Monterey with Groovy version 4 and Gradle as a build tool.

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow, here you can [ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What you've posted is a statement of fact without any question you want answered. Do you just wanted to share your observation or are you seeking some answers?

Comment: Hi @LeonardBrünings, I guess my question is, how I can evaluate a specific line with variables from the "where" area. I edited the original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked for me when I declared the parameters explicitly.

```
def 'simple assertion'(int a, int b, int max) {
    expect:
    Math.max(a, b) == max

    where:
    a | b | max
    3 | 5 | 5
    4 | 9 | 9
}
```

Comment: Seems like this was what I am missing. Thanks a lot!